# Set global headers for all axios request in angular 13 app

Tags: axios, http-headers, angular13

So I am trying to set bearer token for authorization in my angular 13 app but can't seem to find a proper way to set global headers for all axios request so that I don't have to manually set headers for each request. Is it possible..? if so what file do I have to create/update?

I tried using HTTP Client as shown in the angular docs but its pretty hectic and I would have to change all my axios request to http request...